# How can I check database and storage usage in new firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

After I migrated my app to console.firebase.google.com I cannot view the database usage quota, bandwidth usage and several other statistics in the firebase.com analytics tab. Is there any way to check this using new panel?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Update**: you can now see your project's [Realtime Database](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/usage/current-billing/connections), [Cloud Storage](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/storage/usage/current-billing/total_bytes), and [Hosting](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/hosting/usage/current-billing/storage) usage in the Firebase console.

---

*Update (20160727): you can now see your project's database usage from the Firebase Console. Thanks for your patience!*

*Previous answer: the database usage quota charts are not yet available in the [new Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). We're working on adding them, as well as adding similar charts for Storage and Hosting. Hang in there!*

Comment: Please do it as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I understand this is not a firebase user forum, but any update on this? We'd really like to avoid surprises where someone from google says (limits up, upgrade now!!)

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen any updates ? we'd like to estimate the cost of our app.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen this works great in the hosting and database sections. Is there any plan to do something similar in the storage section? Figuring out how much storage you're using is hard - the best way I've found to do it is running gsutil du which isn't ideal

Comment: Please! do it because we are facing "SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException" due to low disk space. Described here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()

Comment: How can i get bandwidth and storage use by one specific user ?

Comment: More than one year have past, still without storage usage, same thing on GCS. I mean they calculate the price somehow.

Answer (score 14):

I see a new Usage tab now. Console > Database > Usage

Currently shows Sent Bytes, Storage and Connections. Looks like it may not be stable yet, because it does not match the stats reflected in my billing section.

Comment: moreover (writing in mid Sep 2016) the functionality seems to be taken down since a week ago or so. There seemed to be some issues with it until now, most of our traffic would not get recognised and reported. I'm sure it will be back online soon, seeing how the Realtime Database Usage is a great tool this will certainly be fixed in no time.