# How to check firebase realtime database pricing/usage

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, price, firebase-console, usage-tracking

I'm looking to use firebase's realtime database for a few different projects and if I select the 3rd and final subscription option it changes price per month based on usage ( if I'm not mistaken ). I want to make sure that if I choose this 3rd option of payment that it's something my app can provide sufficent funds for each individual user. Is there a way I can check how much the third option would cost based on recent usage or can I find out how much data it's currently using them I can manually compare them?

Comment: That information is not yet exposed in the Firebase console. We're working on it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373038/how-can-i-check-database-and-storage-usage-in-new-firebase-console

Comment: is there an estimated release for this feature? It makes it a bit difficult to figure out pricing. Also is it possible to login into the old firebase console to find out that way everytime i try to it just logs me into the new console.

Comment: The feature is actively being worked on, but we don't give any estimates. If your project was created on (or upgraded to) the new console (firebase.google.com), you can't see the stats through the legacy console (firebase.com).

Comment: Alright thanks for the quick response is there a place i can check average memory stored and transferred to a server?