# Firebase Storage totals not available

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

How can I see the total storage and bandwidth use for Firebase Storage? Real Time data totals are easy to see, but not Storage totals and usage.

Comment: can you explore more ?

Comment: you can see maximum limit https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Realtime database usage is now viewable. There is no equivalent chart for storage yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373038/how-can-i-check-database-and-storage-usage-in-new-firebase-console

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming it's about a product feature.

Comment: How would I close it?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald, can I rather delete this question please. Somehow with having this unanswered I am blocked from answering anyone else's question. This is the only question I have asked on Stack overflow.
It seems a bit harsh as I have no way of correcting it. One question unanswered and I am blocked from answering anyone else? Is that correct?

Comment: @GerhardPretorius not sure why you'd be blocked from asking questions, are you actually unable to ask any new questions?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald, I am block from answering any questions. Have not had a question to ask yet, but have seen a few which I could have help answering.

Comment: I believe that's simply a limitation on the amount of Stack Overflow rep you have. After you ask a few questions you get enough rep to start answering them.